# Style certain rows from database table in html table

Tags: html, css, mysql

I have a html table received from this query:

```
SELECT proj_title, CONCAT(projectNo, " ", proj_title) AS title
FROM (
        SELECT projectNo, CONCAT("Project ", title) AS proj_title, 0 AS a FROM project p1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT projectNo, process, 1 AS a FROM process p2
    ) t
ORDER BY projectNo, a, title
```

And table:

```
<table class="paginated" style=" margin-right:10%;">
<?php
$header ='<th>Title</th>';
echo "<thead>$header</thead>";
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) 
{
        $projectNo = $data['proj_title'];


        $body = '<td>'.$projectNo.'</td>';
        echo "<tbody>$body</tbody>";

}
?>    
</table>
```

The table looks like this:

```
|     title       |
+-----------------+
| Project test    |
| ANM             |
| BLD             |
| Project test2   |
| ANM KEY         | 
| BLD             |
```

Is there any way to style only certain rows like: | ***Project test***    || ***Project test2***   |

How it can be done?

Comment: Why not add that asterisks in the `echo`?Or add a class to the `td` that holds it

Comment: so every td is going to be contained by a tbody?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you certainly can style individual rows in a table with CSS. Your provided structure doesn't actually include any table rows (`<tr>` elements), so you might want to fix that up first. `<tbody>` is not a valid child of `<td>`, and `<td>` must be contained inside a `<tr>`.

Once you fix up your table structure, you can target every nth row with the pseudo-selector `:nth-of-type`:

```css
tr:nth-of-type(3n) {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Four</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Five</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Six</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In the above sample, `3n` represents that it should target every third row, and change the colour.

You could also alternatively add a `class` to the specific rows that you wish to target through PHP itself, and then simply target that class directly with CSS:

```
echo "<tr class='red'><td>$data</td></tr>";

.red {
  color: #ff0;
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: what if it is not exactly every 3rd row. it can be different. it depends on amount of processes inside each project

Comment: Then you would need to alter you PHP to assign the class specific to the elements that you wish to target, based on some sort of conditional (which only you would know). Check my second option, which adds the class `red` to specific rows. You'll need to use that within a condition that specifies which rows to target :)

Comment: Thanks for an idea.